# It was too late to stop the malcontents with a show of force. (prepositional phrase)

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> It was too late to stop the malcontents with a show of force.

'with a show of force' modifies 'the malcontents' or 'stop'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @colinfine but let me say it another way.

Let's take a slighly different sentence. Suppose someone wrote, "It was useless to stop the attacker with a gun." Taking this sentence by itself, it is ambiguous. It could mean that the attacker had a gun. Or it could mean that it would be useless to try to use a gun to stop the attacker.

But often in such cases, while grammatically the phrase could modify either the verb or the object, logically only one reading makes sense.

Like if I wrote, "I fought the bear with sharp claws", grammatically this could mean that the bear had sharp claws, or it could mean that I used sharp claws to fight him. But we would normally understand that sentence to mean that the bear had sharp claws, simply because sharp claws are something that a bear normally has and human beings don't.

I'm suddenly reminded of a news story I saw once with the headline, "Enraged bull attacks farmer with axe". Of course the writer meant that the farmer had an axe, but the first time I read it the picture in my head was a bull with an axe attacking a farmer.

In your example, we would normally expect the authorities to use a show of force to suppress malcontents. If the malcontents used violence, we probably wouldn't call that a "show of force", we'd be more like to say something like "rioting and looting".

But if the sentence had said, "It was too late to stop the malcontents with molotov cocktails", readers would almost surely understand that to mean that the malcontents were throwing molotov cocktails, not that the police were using molotov cocktails to stop the malcontents, because molotov cocktails are something that rioters use, but police don't.

The larger context might change the assumptions we would make if we read the sentence in isolation. Like if it said, "The police had run out of bullets and smoke grenades and were resorting to throwing rocks and molotov cocktails at the protesters. But it was too late to stop the malcontents with molotov cocktails", that would reverse the assumptions I would make about the meaning.

Note that this sort of ambiguity is often used in jokes. Say a sentence where the listener will normally assume you mean one thing, then make a further statement that indicates that assumption was wrong. Like:

Al: I have a terrible headache.

Bob: When I have a headache, I go to my wife, and she kisses me and caresses me until I forget all about the headache. You should try it.

Al: That sounds like a great idea! Is she home now?

Answer (score 2):

It modifies *stop*, but I come to this conclusion mostly because of the semantics rather than for syntactic reasons.

Compare

> It was too late to stop the malcontents with the level of popular support.

which is at least ambiguous, and probably attaches to the malcontents; but it would be usual to make this clearer, eg "with the level of their popular support".